# unable to send html email using Google api

Tags: javascript, google-api

I want to send an email with html tags and I am using this line of code for send email.

```
var mailLink = "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&source=mailto&su
=" + title + " &body=" + body;

window.open(mailLink);
```

And in the body part I have a `<a>` tag just link `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`.
But the issue is when we compose this mail and the body part of this mail dose not show me this link.
is theire any way to send this email with this link.Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: escape() the body  tried ?

Comment: In the body we have this text "Hello friend this is test mail.Click on this link for <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>".when window.open function is fired then it show me the compose mail UI with this body but in the body content we can't see this link.

Comment: escape(body)  tried ?

Comment: can you tall me in more detail?var mailLink = "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&source=mailto&su
=" + title + " &body=" + escape(body) am i right or wrong?

Comment: escape(body) does not work.